# how to get the rows which doesn't have data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called Temp with around 15 columns.
In that table col1 is primary key and remaining all are normal keys(which may have null values)
I have inserted the data in the table along with date(in col15).
If the data is not available for all the columns except primary key column, then 
I inserted the primary key column value and the date column value (colulmn 15) 
and for all remaining columns null values.

```
Temp
------------------------------------------------------
col1  col2 col3 col4 col5 ....................col15
------------------------------------------------------
o124  xxx   xxx  xxx  null                    2019-10-17
o236  null  xxx  xxx  xxxx                    2019-10-17
o437  xxx   xxx  null xxxx                    2019-10-17
o448  xxx   null xxx  xxxx                    2019-10-17
o456  null  null null null                    2019-10-17
o458  null  null null null                    2019-10-17
```

Now I want to get the rows which don't have values in all the columns except primary key column (column1) and date column (column 15).

The output would be

```
------------------------------------------------------
col1  col2 col3 col4 col5 ....................col15
------------------------------------------------------
o456  null  null null null                  2019-10-17
o458  null  null null null                  2019-10-17
```

What should be the query I need to write.

Thanks

Comment: *"I want to get the rows which don't have values in all the columns"* - You should be a bit more eloquent in explaining this. That's one of the reasons we insist on posting the  expected output in tabular format.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please have a look once.

Answer (score 3):

"Find where All columns except 1 and 15 are null":

```
SELECT * 
FROM temp
WHERE
  --col1 is PK and won't be null so we don't need to check it
  col2 IS NULL AND
  col3 IS NULL AND
  ...
  col14 IS NULL AND
  col15 IS NOT NULL --check it if it's a hard requirement that it must still have a value
```

Note that while the query from Tejash will work, as a general rule try and avoid using functions that operate on table values, in the where clause as it means oracle has to evaluate the result of the function for every row (which could be millions of evaluations) and it generally disables the use of indexes )unless a functional index is specified, which is rare). In this case it's unlikely that this query could even be indexed sensibly unless you create another column with a flag to indicate whether all fields are null but thisbadvuce serves as a caution for true more general case; for example don't convert a million dates to string to compete them against a single string parameter, convert the single string parameter to a date and compare it to the date in the table (nonconverting row data)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `coalesce` function:

```
Select * from your_table 
Where coalesce(col2, col3, col4, ... , col14) is null;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score -1):

Something like `select * from Temp where (col2 != null or col3 != null or ... or col14 != null)` should be fine.

Comment: I think you should compare it with null. (`Is null` and `is not null` are comparision syntax when it comes to null comparision)

Comment: Requires AND, not or